# nvidia-settings error: nvidia driver not in use

Tags: 12.04, settings, nvidia-optimus, external-monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [External displays with Bumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103564/external-displays-with-bumblebee)

I have an Asus with GEFORCE GT520M CUDA (Optimus) and I am running Kubuntu 12.04, 64bit. I am trying to connect an external monitor through DVI and the monitor is not detected. Nvidia settings dont show properly and each time I fire them up there is a warning message: "You do not appear to be using the NVidia X driver. Please, edit...." (you probably know it and heard of this before).

I have googled a  lot and I have tried some things out but no luck so far. Is there a solution which has worked for someone out there? If so, please be very specific about what I need to do since I am really not good at using the terminal and generally new to ubuntu. I can use the terminal only to copy-paste things. :)

Thanks in advance to everyone!

ps. Seems like some people dealt with this by fixing the Nvidia settings problem but the instructions have never been clear enough for me to be able to understand.

Comment: hi guys and thanks for the quick replies. I have actually installed Bumblebee (seems to be the only solution) but I do not really understand what it does and if there is something more I should do after installing. ps. for the record I had the nvidia-current driver and nvidia-settings installed without doing anything, meaning it was there right after the OS installation was complete.
pps. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

As you have said your system has optimus technology enabled.  Normal drivers of nvidia doesn't work here. You need to install "[Bumblebee](http://www.bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu)"

I am deducing that you have already installed it as you said you can run `nvidia-settings`.  If not you need to install it . If you tried some other solution like old ironhide that I would suggest to have fresh install.

For more information to know why optimus enabled laptop all these things read the links below.

A multi monitor setup guide is available for bumblebee. Which can be found over here 
https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup

More readings,

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki

[How well will Nvidia Optimus cards be supported in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/96552/35775)

[Can't use nvidia card/driver on optimus notebook](https://askubuntu.com/q/119449/35775)

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)